# Why is my window disappearing?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm writing a program in objective-c but when I build and go the window is not loading. I can click on the .xib file and tweak the interface but when I run the program the GUI is not loading. Any ideas on why this is happening.

NOTE: I do see a menu bar that shows that my application is running but the GUI is not visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More description is necessary, but at a first guess, I'd say your window's "visible at runtime" box is unchecked in IB.

Beyond that, we need to know:

What kind of application is it? Document-based, or just a plain application? Are there any runtime errors in the console? Compiler warnings you've ignored? Is your window outlet connected to the window? Is there any code executed at startup (like -application:didFinishLaunching: or -windowControllerDidLoadNib or -awakeFromNib)? If so, list it.

Comment: It is a document-based app BTW